# How to get AES-128-GCM with Ruby 2.3.1

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, aes, aes-gcm

I am using OpenSSL 1.0.2k with Ruby 2.3.1, which supports the "aes-128-gcm", not "AES-128-GCM", algorithm. Ruby 2.4.0 supports both of them when bundled with OpenSSL 1.0.2k.

Where exactly does the difference lie between the two? Does being case-sensitive matter?

I couldn't find an answer. How do I get AES-128-GCM with Ruby 2.3.1?

Comment: Where did you search? What did you try? Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's 2.3.1 OpenSSL documentation says in "[Instantiating a Cipher](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#class-OpenSSL::Cipher-label-Instantiating+a+Cipher)":

> The most generic way to create a Cipher is the following

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('<name>-<key length>-<mode>')
```

> That is, a string consisting of the hyphenated concatenation of the individual components name, key length and mode. *Either all uppercase or all lowercase strings may be used*, for example:

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-128-CBC')
```

(The added emphasis is mine.)

In other words, `'AES-128-GCM'` or `'aes-128-gcm'` is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have checked out the documentation of OpenSSL(Ruby 2.3.1), when I try instantiating 'AES-128-GCM' (`OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-128-GCM')`) I get **RuntimeError: unsupported cipher algorithm (AES-128-GCM)**. Where as when instantiating by 'aes-128-gcm' (`OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-128-gcm')`) it works completely fine, so my question was where exactly difference lies in both?

Comment: It is working with `OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :GCM)`. Thank You.